# Calling a stored procedure from an insert in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am attempting to create a stored proc (MS SQL Server 2012) that copies a number of rows and then inserts them back into the same table with an association to a different foreign table. On the copied rows we also alter the updateddate and createddate, as well as the user who created and updated these new, inserted rows.

This all works fine, until we come to the primary key. The database is that of Sage CRM - this uses a stored procedure (eware_get_identity_id) to grab next primary key id for the table we are inserting into. This eware_get_identity_id stored proc does various inserts, updates and deletes to other tables, so we can not use functions instead. We cannot change the make up of the database, so changing the type of the column to an Identity specification is not an option either.

What I want to do (and I know I can not) is something like the below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Lead_CopySecuritiesToOpp
    @lead_leadID int,
    @oppo_opportunityID int,
    @user_userID int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO Security
            (<columns hidden for clarity>,secu_CreatedDate,secu_UpdatedDate,secu_CreatedBy,secu_UpdatedBy, 
                         secu_LeadId, secu_CaseId,secu_SecurityID)
    SELECT  <columns hidden for clarity>, GETDATE() as secu_CreatedDate, GETDATE() as secu_UpdatedDate, @user_userID as secu_CreatedBy, 
             @user_userID as secu_UpdatedBy, NULL as secu_LeadId, @oppo_opportunityID as secu_CaseId,
             (exec [dbo].[eware_get_identity_id] 'Security') as secu_SecurityID
        FROM            Security
        WHERE        (secu_LeadId = @lead_leadID)

END
GO
```

Clearly I cannot execute a stored procedure inline in this way (**(exec [dbo].[eware_get_identity_id] 'Security') as secu_SecurityID**). A function would be ideal if the Sage SP didn't change data, however it does, so this is not an option. Can anyone suggest a better way of doing this? I did think about resorting to cursors, or perhaps a temporary table to get the data right before insert? Suggestions please.

Comment: Have you considered making it transactional? Assuming you are just calling sprocs that do inserts/updates etc, you should be able to wrap the whole operation in a transaction, and rollback should anything go wrong. Then you can safely call the identity generate function and insert as two separate statements without the possibility that you have an inconsistent database should something go wrong

Comment: If you cannot change the makeup of the database, then how can you Create/Alter this `Lead_CopySecuritiesToOpp` stored procedure?  Are there some things that you *can* change/add to the database?

Comment: Hmm, have you looked at something called `eware_get_identity_id_range`?  It looks like it was written to address this problem.  See here: https://community.sagecrm.com/user_community/f/84/p/3205/10691.aspx#10691, the post mentioning it is about halfway down...

Comment: @RBarryYoung, Lead_CopySecuritiesToOpp is my own SP, I can create new SPs, just can't alter existing system SPs or tables. I will take a look at that SQL to see if it can assist. Ta

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a cursor to execute the SP for each row. There will only ever be one or two rows executed at a time - so this solution works (even if it isn't exactly beautiful).

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Lead_CopySecuritiesToOppo
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @lead_leadID int,
    @oppo_opportunityID int,
    @user_userID int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @secu_SecurityID char( 11 )
    declare @newsecu_SecurityID int

    set rowcount 0
    select * into #mytemp from Security where secu_LeadId = @lead_leadID

    set rowcount 1

    select @secu_SecurityID = secu_SecurityID from #mytemp

    --Cursor through all the returned security rows
    while @@rowcount <> 0
    begin
        set rowcount 0

        --Get the next ID
        EXEC @newsecu_SecurityID = [dbo].[eware_get_identity_id] 'Security'

        --Insert this row into the security table
        INSERT INTO Security
                        (secu_TimeStamp, secu_Deleted, secu_Secterr, secu_Name, 
                         secu_Status, secu_propType, secu_typeN, secu_noBeds, secu_noFloors, secu_noFlats, secu_purpBuilt, secu_stanConst, 
                         secu_stanConstN, secu_yearBuilt, secu_tenure, secu_leaseLeft, secu_exLEA, secu_exLEAN, secu_adjComP, secu_adjComPN, secu_letToFam, 
                         secu_letToFamN, secu_tenType, secu_purPrice, secu_purPrice_CID, secu_purchasedDate, secu_estValue, secu_estValue_CID, secu_reinstval, 
                         secu_reinstval_CID, secu_rentInc, secu_rentInc_CID, secu_valCont, secu_valTel, secu_loanType, secu_address1, secu_address2, secu_address3, 
                         secu_address4, secu_postcode, secu_primary,secu_CreatedDate,secu_UpdatedDate,secu_CreatedBy,secu_UpdatedBy, 
                             secu_LeadId, secu_CaseId,secu_SecurityID)
        SELECT              secu_TimeStamp, secu_Deleted, secu_Secterr, secu_Name, 
                             secu_Status, secu_propType, secu_typeN, secu_noBeds, secu_noFloors, secu_noFlats, secu_purpBuilt, secu_stanConst, 
                             secu_stanConstN, secu_yearBuilt, secu_tenure, secu_leaseLeft, secu_exLEA, secu_exLEAN, secu_adjComP, secu_adjComPN, secu_letToFam, 
                             secu_letToFamN, secu_tenType, secu_purPrice, secu_purPrice_CID, secu_purchasedDate, secu_estValue, secu_estValue_CID, secu_reinstval, 
                             secu_reinstval_CID, secu_rentInc, secu_rentInc_CID, secu_valCont, secu_valTel, secu_loanType, secu_address1, secu_address2, secu_address3, 
                             secu_address4, secu_postcode, secu_primary, GETDATE() as secu_CreatedDate, GETDATE() as secu_UpdatedDate, @user_userID as secu_CreatedBy, 
                             @user_userID as secu_UpdatedBy, NULL as secu_LeadId, @oppo_opportunityID as secu_CaseId, @newsecu_SecurityID as secu_SecurityID
        FROM            #mytemp where secu_SecurityID = @secu_SecurityID

        delete #mytemp where secu_SecurityID = @secu_SecurityID

        set rowcount 1
        select @secu_SecurityID = secu_SecurityID from #mytemp
    end
    set rowcount 0

END
GO
```